# problem in sending mail by gmail smtp in server but works fine in localhost

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, pear

I have opened a site in a free web hosting company which is not offering `mail()` facility so I have decided to implement this facility of sending emails using G-mail's SMTP server.

I have used PEAR' [Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) package  to send mails. It works fine locally but unfortunately its not all working in my website's server.

When the page is opened, it produces a blank white screen even no errors are being mentioned. You can check [here](http://kkkcodes.byethost33.com/mail1.php) to see the script run.

This is my code:

```
<?php

   require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "username@gmail.com";
    $to = "username@yahoo.com";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "username@gmail.com";
    $password = "*****";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));


    $mail= $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }

?>
```

Can anyone help me to understand what's going wrong?

Comment: Activate error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I get an http 500 error trying to open your site.  Which suggests some syntax error somewhere

Comment: `$ HEAD http://kkkcodes.byethost33.com/mail1.php
403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 0):

You maybe forgot to upload the `Mail.php` file or one of the dependencies. A white page often indicates a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail blocks some web hosting providers. Contact you your web hosting provider.